Getting the Harmonic Mean of Three Numbers from Arithmetic and Geometric Mean
I have been stuck to this problem:
Given three numbers a, b, c, their arithmetic mean which is 10, and their geometric mean which is 8, find the value of the harmonic mean.
I now know that:
$a+b+c=30$
$abc=512$
$HM = 1536/(ab+bc+ac)$
How do I get HM?

Where does $1536$ come from?

@JoséCarlosSantos The HM is $\frac{3}{1/a+\cdots}$, but $1/a=bc/8^3$.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Calling the HM $h$, the numbers are the roots of $x^3-30x^2+tx-512$ with $t=1536/h$. You can't make $t$ unique without some other constraint. For example, are $a,,b,,c$ positive integers? (Actually, they can't be.)

That is the problem, there are no given additional information.

Agree with @j-g that the problem does not have a unique solution. As an example, note that {3.68269, 7.31731, 19} and {5.16174, 19.8383, 5} both satisfy the AM and GM constraints but have different harmonic means: 6.51 and 6.75 respectively

Thank you very much!
